# Removing parametrization from a system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, parametric

Consider the following system :

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2} &=
-f\left(t\right)\frac{d t}{d \lambda}\frac{d t}{d \lambda}
-A\frac{d g\left(t,x\right)}{d \lambda}\frac{d t}{d \lambda}+
B\frac{\partial g\left(t,x\right)}{\partial t}\left(\frac{d t}{d \lambda}\right)^2
\\
\frac{d^2x}{d\lambda^2} &=
-f\left(t\right)\frac{d t}{d \lambda}\frac{d x}{d \lambda}
+A\frac{d g\left(t,x\right)}{d \lambda}\frac{d x}{d \lambda}
-B\frac{\partial g\left(t,x\right)}{\partial x}\left(\frac{d t}{d \lambda}\right)^2
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $f$ depends only on $t$, $g$ depends on $t$ and $x$, and $A$ and $B$ are two constants.
Is there a way to rewrite this system without $\lambda$ in order to obtain :

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} =\quad ?$$

Comment: In the second equation replace all derivatives with respect to $\lambda$ by $\frac {\cdot}{dt} \frac{dt}{d\lambda}$. The second derivative $\frac {d^2 x}{d^2\lambda}=\frac{d^2 x}{d^2 t} (\frac{d t}{d \lambda})^2$. You will get everywhere  the multiplier $(\frac{d t}{d \lambda})^2$ that  can be  removed